# Large Battery Cell mounting in Enclosure

Tags: batteries, pcb, pcb-design, enclosure, mounting-holes

I am trying to figure out the best way to mount a battery like this (http://www.batteryspace.com/polymerli-ionmodule37v10000mah37wh85arate-prewiredwithpcbpl9059156.aspx) onto a 8" x 6" PCB.  There do not seem to be standard holders like there are for 18650 or AA sizes. Are there standard techniques for holding these types of cells in place properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the most comon practice I see in use is to use a double sided sticky foam and attach the battery to the bottom side of the board.use a thick enough foam so that the compression of it does not allow for the components to peirce the battery pack which would explode.

Answer (score 0):

There are no apparent standards for the size or even shape of those new-generation batteries.  If you can afford the PC board space, the most reliable method is probably to provide a large rectangular space for the battery to lie flat, and provide holes for a couple of plastic ties to secure the battery to the board.  That way the battery can be removed and replaced by the end-user when necessary.

It would be user-friendly to use a standard quick-connect like a JST plug of the appropriate size for the current.